# scaling a bitmap without losing quality

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe2

i have a little problem .. i am developing an SkinEngine that allow Delphi Vcl Application to be Skined . for this goal, i had developed a new file format (mSkin) in order to host my skin data .so my skin file contains 2 header , the first contains some information about the colors used by the skin , the second contains the bitmap used by skin (the bitmap type is Alpha channel bitmap in order to support transparency ).in my control i use a function to extract object bitmap from the bitmap(mSkin.Bitmap) and draw this bitmap onto my control . the problem is that when the bitmap is not shaped i got a bad quality when scaling the source bitmap .the size of the object bitmap is proportional to the control size (when the contol size changed ==> the bitmap siwe change too .)
[image]

i had try to read the vcl style to solve the problem .. but it seems to be very difficult to read .
is there a way to copy bitmap and Maintaining the quality ?

Comment: Why don't you **use** VCL styles?

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt : it's for the education purpose .

Answer (score 4):

If you use bitmaps you simple can't do scaling without the problems you have. If you want  scaling where e.g. a one-pixel border stays a one-pixel border, then you have to use a vector-based format for your images.

Comment: I would suggest e.g. [`SVG format`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). For Delphi, there is a few [`libraries available`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607/rendering-svg-with-delphi).

Comment: i believe that we can use bitmap file since the vcl style used the bitmap file format .

Comment: @user1720557 You could alleviate some problems with bitmaps scaling by having a number of pre-scaled bitmaps, and then you don't have to scale so much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to divide that into 9 different bitmaps, like a 3x3 grid. then you only scale the middle on, the rest stay the same size but move. [This link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) is for android but the same principles apply.

Here is [another link](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9/). This is for flash, but it also explains the principle.

Comment: useful technique but doesn't work well in my experience with gradients

Comment: @mark Fair point, but when I've used them like this gradients need to be stretched quite far to show up as a problem.

Comment: Maybe GDI+ (http://sourceforge.net/projects/igdiplus/) my help on resampling the image for gradients

Comment: @Finlaybob it s a good technique , but it does not work if the bitmap is eclipsed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a [resampling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(bitmap)).

For upscaling, I like very much the B-Spline.

For simple content like yours, the [hqnx family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hqx) sometimes gives good results, and is very fast to render (even in real-time). For some pascal source code, [you may take a look at this forum thread](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/showthread.php?4165-C-to-Pascal-conversion-hq2x).

See also [this more general question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-to-enlarge-an-image-with-as-little-pixelation-as-possible).